# Run Codeigniter controller using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: php, codeigniter, windows-task-scheduler

I want to run a CodeIgniter controller periodically using Windows Task Scheduler like a cron job. I have run a standalone PHP file using task scheduler with [this](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/running-php-scripts-as-cron-jobs-on-windows) method, but failed to implement this on a CodeIgniter controller.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
defined("BASEPATH") OR exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Cron_test extends CI_Controller {

    public $file;
    public $path;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper("file");
        $this->load->helper("directory");

        $this->path = "application" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "cron_test" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $this->file = $this->path . "cron.txt";
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $date = date("Y:m:d h:i:s");
        $data = $date . " --- Cron test from CI";

        $this->write_file($data);
    }

    public function write_file($data)
    {
        write_file($this->file, $data . "\n", "a");
    }
}
```

I want to run the `index()` method periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Make your write_file() as private or protected method to disallow use of it from browsers. Set crontab on your server (if Linux, or Time Schedule if Windows server). Use full path of `$path` (i.e. `$this->path = APPPATH . "cron_test" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;`). Use double check to see if cli request is made.
Something like:

```
<?php
defined("BASEPATH") OR exit("No direct script access allowed");

class Cron_test extends CI_Controller
{

    public $file;
    public $path;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper("file");
        $this->load->helper("directory");

        $this->path = APPPATH . "cron_test" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $this->file = $this->path . "cron.txt";
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->is_cli_request())
        {
            $date = date("Y:m:d h:i:s");
            $data = $date . " --- Cron test from CI";

            $this->write_file($data);
        }
        else
        {
            exit;
        }
    }

    private function write_file($data)
    {
        write_file($this->file, $data . "\n", "a");
    }
}
```

Than, on your server set crontab. That could looks something like:

```
* 12 * * * /var/www/html/index.php cli/Cron_test
```

(This one would make action every day at noon). [Cron reference on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: Thanks for helping, but if there is a way to pass this `index` function in windows task scheduler?....

Here what I have done for a single php file..

Under **Create New Task > Action > New** tab I have passed path of php.exe in `program/script` field and  **-f C:\wamp\www\cron.php** in `add arguments` field. Here `cron.php` is my file which runs periodically....


What should I pass in `add arguments` field to do such things for a controller, or there's another way to do such things?

Comment: I made some changes in answer. Try now. Btw. update question with code from comment to be more readable.